# How to write function that returns an existing TForm instance at runtime?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm trying to write a function that returns either of two `TForm` instances, according to the user-set configuration:

```
function TfrmMain.GetCurrentRamEditFrm: TForm;
{ Get the RAM Editor Form instance according to currenttly-set protocol. }
begin
  if frmSetup.GetCurrentProtocol() = FooBus then
    result := RAM_Editor_FooBus.frmRAM_Editor_FooBus
  else
    result := RAM_Editor_SXcp.frmRAM_Editor_SXcp;
end;
```

I need this function because this unit (`Main.pas`) reads/writes a lot of variables in the RAM Editor Form.

The compiler trips up on lines like:

`GetCurrentRamEditFrm().StatusBar1.Panels[1].Text := get_text(96);`

with the error message: `Undeclared identifier 'StatusBar1'`

If I provide the TForm instance explicitely there is no error:

`RAM_Editor_SXcp.frmRAM_Editor_SXcp.StatusBar1.Panels[1].Text := get_text(96);`

`StatusBar` is declared like this, in both Forms:

```
type
  TfrmRAM_Editor_SXcp = class(TForm)
    StatusBar1: TStatusBar; // i.e. the scope is "published"
    ...
```

Interestingly, the compiler doesn't mind the following:

`GetCurrentRamEditFrm().show();`

Comment: Have you considered the use of RTTI?

Comment: @Caputo That looks like an advanced feature which I don't fully understand. But I'll read more about it later, thanks.

Comment: I've posted an example. If you'd like I can make it deeper! Best regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler error is quite understandable because `TForm` does not have a member named `StatusBar1`. You introduced that in your derived forms, which I presume are of type `TfrmRAM_Editor_FooBus` and `TfrmRAM_Editor_SXcp`.

Now, if the two forms derive from a common base that introduces `StatusBar1` you could return that common base class instead and your code would compile. This would look like this:

```
type
  TfrmRAM_Editor_Base = class(TForm)
    StatusBar1: TStatusBar;
    ....
  end;

  TfrmRAM_Editor_FooBus = class(TfrmRAM_Editor_Base)
    ....
  end;

  TfrmRAM_Editor_SXcp = class(TfrmRAM_Editor_Base)
    ....
  end;

function TfrmMain.GetCurrentRamEditFrm: TfrmRAM_Editor_Base;
{ Get the RAM Editor Form instance according to currently-set protocol. }
begin
  if frmSetup.GetCurrentProtocol() = FooBus then
    result := RAM_Editor_FooBus.frmRAM_Editor_FooBus
  else
    result := RAM_Editor_SXcp.frmRAM_Editor_SXcp;
end;
```

However, that doesn't feel like a great solution. The problem I have with this is that inheritance is a very rigid mechanism, and I am not happy at all with exposing UI controls to be used outside the form itself. In realise that Delphi's streaming mechanism forces design-time controls to be published and therefore visible from the outside, but in my view that was a terrible mistake that promotes poor design.

Personally I'd define an interface that can be used to set status text.

```
type
  ISetStatusText = interface
    [...add GUID here]
    procedure SetStatusText(const Value: string);
  end;
```

Have each form implement this interface and then you can query for it using `as`. Or perhaps better, have your `GetCurrentRamEditFrm` function return the interface rather than the form.

This avoids your having to expose the form's UI implementation details to all and sundry.

Comment: That is a good solution; thank you for helping me. But, since the compiler doesn't trip over lines where the Form instance is explicitely provided (like I showed in my question), surely there's some way to make a function return the reference/pointer to a specific Form instance, no? This would be a lot less work.

Comment: @NewWorld You have two forms and each of those forms has its own class, you cannot write function that will return both classes at same time. You need to introduce some common ground and to achieve that your forms either have to descend from same base type that has functionality you need or they have to share same interface. There is no other way.

Comment: Well, which one do you want the function to return? You only get one return type. And it's set in stone at compile time. You cannot have the function return one type sometimes, and another type some other times. Hence the suggestion to use a common base type. However, I cannot stress strongly enough that exposing UI controls like that is bad practice. I would not advocate doing so.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar You guys are really great :) There aren't many Delphi resources out there so I don't think I would've found this advice or clear explanation elsewhere. Thank you both

Comment: @David, why not create a virtual method `SetStatusText` (maybe even a a setter of property `StatusText`) in the base class instead of the interface? ancestors could override it if needed. although I must admit, I have never seen a virtual setter or maybe I'm too senile.

Comment: @kobik Because inheritance is an incredible crude tool. Suppose you have another form that cannot share the common base, but has the capability of displaying status text.

Comment: @David, not sure I follow. what do you mean by "cannot share the common base"? is it derived from the base?

Comment: @kobik Suppose that the common base introduces the virtual method to set status text. But then you have another common base to introduce a virtual method for some other purpose, logging say. What if you need a form with status text, but no logging, one with logging but not status text, and one with both. At this point inheritance fails you. On the other hand, interfaces avoid that problem. They simply declare that a class is capable of offering some service.

Comment: @David, I see your point now. thanks. what I would normally do, is to virtually offer some services via inheritance in the base class (without actually implementing them). this might be totally wrong.

Comment: @kobik Inheritance is a rather weak tool in my view, and is massively overused.

Comment: and sorry for my typo on the comment: "...`ancestors` could override it if needed" should be `descendants` of course.

Comment: @David you can have it both way. You can have common base class with some methods and then if needed introduce interface with those methods for other classes that cannot inherit from common base class. While interfaces are the most flexible solution there is nothing wrong with using common base classes in simple cases.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar That isn't having it both ways. That's using interfaces.

Comment: @David That is using interfaces on top of common base class. And you can start just with common base class and add interfaces if really needed. It all depends on what kind of problem you have to solve.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar All classes have a common base. What exactly is your point? That all problems can be solved by inheritance?

Comment: @David Yeah, all classes have `TObject` as ancestor. If you read carefully you will see that I am not trying to solve all problems with inheritance, I am just not keen on dismissing inheritance as valid solution to *some* problems. After all, interfaces do not provide implementation, and with inheritance you can put common implementation under same roof, and yes I know you can also use delegation to achieve it but that is another story.

Comment: @Dalija Yes implementation inheritance can be useful sometimes but it is massively overrated.

Comment: @kobik There is nothing wrong in using common base class with virtual methods. It all depends on the problem you are solving and how you predict code will grow in the future.

Comment: @Dalija There's something wrong when it doesn't work or leads to a poor design

Comment: @David I have to agree that inheritance is abused at large, but problem does not lie in inheritance rather in people trying to screw the nail. Almost everything can lead to poor design choices if people are not trained how to use it.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar, Yeah I know there is nothing wrong with it. the entire VCL (almost) is build on inheritance. I think they did a pretty good job.

Comment: @dalija I contend that inheritance is the wrong tool here

Comment: @David quite possible, but we would have to know more about forms in question to be able to say that without any doubt. Also, people need to learn how to walk before they can run. Sometimes doing easier thing, no matter how wrong it can be in the long run, is the only way to really go forward.

Comment: @Dalija Well, I'd say that sometimes doing the wrong thing just teaches and cements bad habits.....

Comment: @kobik "_the entire VCL (almost) is build on inheritance. I think they did a pretty good job._" Don't confuse rich functionality with good design. I agree the VCL provides a lot of useful functionality. But I've encountered many practical problems that needed complex or untidy solutions due to the rigidity of a deep inheritance based design. (And more problems still where other developer's tried to mimick Borland's approach.) Many of these problems could have been avoided with a better design relying more on composition.

Answer (score 10):

Your function returns instance as `TForm` that does not know anything about `StatusBar1` you have declared in `TfrmRAM_Editor_SXcp`.

`GetCurrentRamEditFrm().show();` works because `TForm` class has method `Show`.

You would have to either create base form type that will declare all variables and methods you want to use or declare interface that both of your forms will share.

**Solution 1:**

```
type
  TBaseForm = class(TForm)
    StatusBar1: TStatusBar;

type
  TfrmRAM_Editor_SXcp = class(TBaseForm)
    // this type will automatically inherit StatusBar1

function TfrmMain.GetCurrentRamEditFrm: TBaseForm;
{ Get the RAM Editor Form instance according to currenttly-set protocol. }
begin
  if frmSetup.GetCurrentProtocol() = FooBus then
    result := RAM_Editor_FooBus.frmRAM_Editor_FooBus
  else
    result := RAM_Editor_SXcp.frmRAM_Editor_SXcp;
end;
```

**Solution 2:**

```
type
  IBaseForm = interface
    procedure SetStatus(const s: string);
  end;

type
  TfrmRAM_Editor_SXcp = class(TForm, IBaseForm)
    StatusBar1: TStatusBar; // i.e. the scope is "published"
    ...
    procedure SetStatus(const s: string);

procedure TfrmRAM_Editor_SXcp.SetStatus(const s: string);
begin
  StatusBar1.Panels[1].Text := s;
end;

function TfrmMain.GetCurrentRamEditFrm: IBaseForm;
{ Get the RAM Editor Form instance according to currenttly-set protocol. }
begin
  if frmSetup.GetCurrentProtocol() = FooBus then
    result := RAM_Editor_FooBus.frmRAM_Editor_FooBus
  else
    result := RAM_Editor_SXcp.frmRAM_Editor_SXcp;
end;
```

You can then use it like this:

```
GetCurrentRamEditFrm().SetStatus(get_text(96));
```

Of course, even if you don't go with interfaced solution, it would be good to introduce methods for functionality you need instead of grabbing UI elements like `StatusBar` directly. And if some day you do need to use interfaces instead of common base class if you already have methods in place then introducing interface would be very easy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use RTTI to do that for you. One advantage of doing this with RTTI is that you do not need to change inheritance or apply interfaces. You will just need to set a published property on the forms

```
type
  TfrmRAM_Editor_SXcp = class(TForm)
  published
    property StatusBar: TStatusBar read FStatusBar write FStatusBar;
    //property StatusBar: TStatusBar read StatusBar1 write StatusBar1; //Alternative
    ...
  end;

constructor TfrmRAM_Editor_SXcp.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  FstatusBar := StatusBar1;
end;
```

With that you can access the status bar using RTTI

```
function TfrmMain.GetRAMFrmStatusBar: TStatusBar;
begin
  if IsPublishedProp(GetCurrentRamEditFrm, 'StatusBar') then
    result :=  GetObjProp(GetCurrentRamEditFrm(), 'StatusBar') as TStatusBar
  else
    result := nil;
end;
```

Or create a setStatusBarText procedure

```
procedure TfrmMain.setRAMFrmStatusBarText(const panelId: integer; const text: string);
begin
  GetRAMFrmStatusBar.Panels[panelId].Text := text;
end;
```

Comment: You still need to initialize `FStatusBar := StatusBar1` for each form (or use getter/setter). or did I miss something?

Comment: Yes, or use StatusBar1 as a field directly to keep it simple

Comment: Well yes you can do this, but why would you want to? Just because you can do it does not make it a good idea. There are a variety of ways to implement the functionality and have compile time type safety. Why would you select RTTI over compile time type safety? -1

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Just pointing another way that is possible to do. Both yours and Dalija's are really good ones, and I saw that maybe the OP would like to see another way to do it

Comment: You could also do this by creating a global variable of type `TStatusBar` and writing to that global variable whenever the protocol changes. But that would be an even worse method. So, yes you could do it this way, but I'm using my voting to register disapproval of this approach.

Comment: @Caputo Before you start trading compile time errors for run time ones, make sure that you will be getting really great deal out of it. And in this case you can only shoot yourself in the foot with RTTI. This is not just another way of doing it.